# Stop automatic ANSI_1252 to UTF-8 encoding when adding a DXF layer?

Tags: qgis, gdal, dxf, encoding

I have a DXF file encoded in ANSI_1252, with object attributes containing umlauts. When I open it in QGIS, the umlauts don't display properly. This apparently happens because QGIS automatically sets the character encoding to UTF-8. In Layer Properties / General the Data source encoding is set to UTF-8 and greyed out, so I can't change it there either. How can I keep the ANSI_1252 encoding?

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution to the problem:
Open the DXF file in a texteditor and save the file with the encoding that is used by QGIS. In my case I had a DXF file exported from AutoCAD with encoding UTF-8, with Swedish text. I found out that by trial and error that saving the DXF-file with ANSI encoding the text was displayed correctly in QGIS.

I used notepad++ to open the DXF-file and converted the encoding to ANSI and saved the file and then opened the file again in QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to GDAL/OGR behaviour not QGIS. As described in [GDAL doc](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dxf.html#config-DXF_ENCODING):

> Normally DXF files are in the ANSI_1252 / Win1252 encoding. GDAL/OGR attempts to translate this to UTF-8 when reading and back into ANSI_1252 when writing. DXF files can also have a header field ($DWGCODEPAGE) indicating the encoding of the file. An attempt is made to use this to recode other code pages to UTF-8. Whether this works will depend on the code page naming and whether GDAL/OGR is built against the iconv library for character recoding.

> In some cases the $DWGCODEPAGE setting in a DXF file will be wrong, or unrecognised by OGR. In this case, [DXF_ENCODING](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dxf.html#config-DXF_ENCODING) may be used to override what id will be used by OGR in transcoding:

> DXF_ENCODING=value: An encoding name supported by [CPLRecode()](https://gdal.org/api/cpl.html#_CPPv49CPLRecodePKcPKcPKc) (i.e. an iconv name), not a DXF $DWGCODEPAGE name. Using a value "UTF-8" will avoid any attempt to recode the text as it is read.

Just add an entry to QGIS environmental variables:

[image]